# How to gain complete access to a heroku-postgresql database via python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, connector

I made a postrgesql database on heroku. Then I tried to access it via a python script. For that I wrote the following code.

```
import psycopg2

#connect to the db 
con = psycopg2.connect(
            host = "an_aws_ec2_instance",
            database="d57kjtuarj5li8",
            user = "mmpywqodjzxlzr",
            password = "************************************")

#cursor 
cur = con.cursor()

#execute query
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE accounts (user_id serial PRIMARY KEY, username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL, password VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL, created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, last_login TIMESTAMP)")
cur.execute = ("""SELECT * FROM accounts""")
rows = cur.fetchall()

for r in rows:
    print (r)

#commit the transcation 
con.commit()

#close the cursor
cur.close()

#close the connection
con.close()
```

But on executing the code, I got the following error.

```
---> 15 cur.execute = ("""SELECT * FROM accounts""")
     16 rows = cur.fetchall()

AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object attribute 'execute' is read-only
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you comapare your two SQL lines, there is a major difference.

This calls the method `execute` on the object `cur`, with the SQL statement as parameter:

```py
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE accounts (user_id serial PRIMARY KEY, username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL, password VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL, created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, last_login TIMESTAMP)")
```

This here is something different. Here you are trying to assign a string (the SQL statement) to an attribute (`execute`), which is read-only on that object.

```
cur.execute = ("""SELECT * FROM accounts""")
#          THIS
```

if remove the `=` from the second statement, you're fine.